# LUA file reading

Tags: file, lua

I am modding a game script where I can locate something in my minimap by getting the specific x,y coordinates. For that, I made a file that stores those values like this :

```
LocationName
X position
Y position
```

So, I came out with that code to read them

```
for line in file:lines() do

            if string.find(line, Location) then

                var1 = file:read("*line")

                var2= ??????????????

            end

        end
```

The X position can be easily read using the read("*line"), But how am I supposed to read the Y position that is underneath?

Comment: @lhf Welp, It did work, idk y I assumed that I tried  it and it failed. Lucid dreams probably, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
        var1 = file:read("*line")
        var2 = file:read("*line")
```